# Choosing capacitor to accommodate for sudden RX current spike

Tags: capacitor, current

I am using a ZigBee CC2530PA module which wakes up every 1 second and turns on the RX. It is only awake for 10 ms @ ~60mA power consumption. However, the module may restart sometimes due to lack of immediate power. I figured that I needed to add capacitors that were fast enough to supply immediate power for this module when it waked up. I may need multiple caps to supply enough power over the 10 ms period as well. So my question is, how do I find the minimum value of caps I'd need & how do figure out how many caps I'd need for this? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Why can't your normal supply provide the 60 mA?

Answer (score 2):

60ma * 10ms is 0.0006C (coulombs)...that's the amount of charge you have to store.

Since capacitance is in C/V (F), you need to find the voltage range over which the CC2530PA will work.  If it's 2.7 to 3.6V, for example, that's a delta-v of 0.9V.  Thus, 0.0006C / 0.9V is 667 uF.

Comment: Your delta-v calculation assumes that the nominal supply voltage is right up at the maximum - it may not be (3V battery maybe?).

Comment: Would a capacitor of this size be fast enough? I heard that "Small capacitors handle fast transients". Would adding an additional small capacitor be necessary?

Comment: Well, for that you need to factor in the peak current and the capacitor ESR and re-evaluate the minimum voltage. Might need a larger capacitor, or several in parallel. Might as well put a 0.1 uF bypass cap on there, too.

Comment: Peak current is ~68mA. How do you determine the specific value of the small bypass cap?

Comment: Over designing this aspect is a good thing.  Having your product fail in service due to small under-voltage, capacitor quality or ambient temperature variations is a very bad idea.   Using 2 or 3 capacitors of the design value in parallel will give you some redundancy and peace of mind.  Select low ESR electrolytics with appropriate temperature range.

Comment: @KalleMP When you say to use 2 or 3 caps, how could I determine the values I need for this application?

Comment: @AlexFeng This answer had a suggested calculation, I did not check it but the offered value was in the believable range.  If you user 3 x 470uF based on this calculation that would give you some margin.  I would also look to other peoples implementations and applications notes for the module and ICs to see what values they recommend.

Comment: @KalleMP I meant to say 2 or 3 caps that are small sized (like .1 uF as mentioned by alex.forencich). How is this small cap value determined?

Comment: @AlexFeng I think the small capacitance to cover the high frequency transients near the IC is hopefully well enough handled by the module, though adding a few more will not hurt.  The need for transient capacitors is to handle the hight (usually) transmit current spikes in RF modules.  The same occurs in GSM modules.  If you do not have a robust battery in close proximity you have to add more capacitors to handle the volt drop in cables and/or PSU.  The peak current is many times higher than the average.

Comment: @KalleMP Let's say I do need small capacitors. How would I calculate their values?

Comment: @AlexFeng The small capacitors are determined by the IC manufacturer and should be implemented on the module.  Check the datasheet, better yet attach it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need a certain charge \$Q\$ to get your module through the burst:

$$ Q= I\cdot T$$

With I being the current draw and T the duration of that current draw.

Now, ignoring the (probably small, otherwise you wouldn't be asking) current sourcing capabilities of your power source, that whole charge must be contained within that capacitor.

Now, a capacitor charged to a specific voltage simply carries

$$ Q = U \cdot C $$

in charge. Now, putting things together:

$$ C = \frac QU = \frac{IT}U $$

Just insert your supply voltage (which must match what the module needs) for U, and multiply the result with at least 4 to get something that doesn't drop too much voltage during the current draw.